# Drop Down Menu in Jquery used as <form> <select>

Tags: jquery, forms, servlets, drop-down-menu, input

I have a JQuery drop down menu like so

```
<div id="dropdownmenu">      
  <ul>  
      <li>
          <p><a href="#">Project</a></p>
          <% for(CProject project: projectList)
          { %>
              <p><a href="#"><%= project.getName() %></a></p>
          <%
          } %>
      </li>   

      <li>  
           <p><a href="#">Table</a></p>  
           <p>Table 1</p>  
      </li>  

      <li>  
           <p><a href="#">Filter</a></p>  
           <p>Filter 1 </p>  
      </li>  
  </ul>
</div>
```

Similar to [this](http://buildinternet.com/live/smoothmenu/animated-menu.html).

What I am trying to do is use each `li` as a `form` `select` and each `p` as a `option`.

Ex: Hover over Project and select the desired project, **form submits and servlet redirects to the same page now with the Table option populated**, then hover over Table and select the desired table and so on...

My only issue is that before when I used `form select`, the option chosen from the drop down list `value` would be placed with the name of the `select` tag as an input. Then I would reference it in the servlet by `request.getParameter("name_of_input");` How would I do this in this case?

Answer (score 0):

I figured a way to make this work

```
<%! int variableName = -1 ; /* This is the **value** for your input */ %> 

<div id="dropdownmenu">  
    <form name="dropdownlist" action="<!--TO YOUR SERVLET-->" method="POST" id="dropdown">

     <ul>  
         <li>
             <p><a href="#">Project</a></p>
             <%for(CProject project: projectList)
               { %>
                   <p><a href="#" onclick="<%variablename = project.getName(); /* This will place the value of the chosen option in the variableName */%> submitform();">
                   <%= project.getName() %></a></p>

               <%
               } %>

              <input type="hidden" name="projectselect" value='<%= variableName %>'/>
         </li>
    </ul>

 </form>
```

I have only shown how to do this for the first `li`, however with more inputs being sent all you need to do is add another variable above between the `<%! %>`, place the hidden `input` at the bottom of the `li` tags and make it's value equal to the variable name you chose. **Refer to code for clarification**

Answer (score 0):

My last answer did not work correctly, here is the fix

```
<div id="dropdownmenu">  
    <form name="dropdownlist" action="<!--Servlet-->" method="POST" id="dropdown">     

        <ul>  
            <li>
                <p><a href="#">Project</a></p>
                 <%  int counter = 0;
                 for(CProject project: projectList)
                 { %>                                                                   <!-- \/ This script submits the form \/-->
                     <p><a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('<%=project.getName()%>').click(); submitform()";>
                     <input id='<%=project.getName()%>' onclick ="this.name = 'nameWanted'"<!--This acts as the name of the <select> tag--> type="hidden" value ="<%= counter %>" <!--This value is different for each option in the for loop --> />
                     <%= project.getName()%></a></p>
                 <%
                     counter++;
                 } %>

                </li>
            </ul>

        </form>
    </div>
```

This way here adds an hidden `input` for each new element. Each input only has a name when the element is clicked and the values are set through the for loop.